# Sqoop export DB2 update-key

Tags: db2, sqoop

I am trying to export data to a db2 database using sqoop export with

```
--update-mode allowinsert
--update-key some_column
```

But I can’t determine if DB2 supports this feature. The sqoop export failure message is cryptic and doesn’t give any information as to what actually failed and I can’t find any examples of this being used specifically for DB2 anywhere.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you run in debug mode using the argument `--verbose` and post the log.

Comment: I did but unfortunately this does not provide any useful information either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further attempts/research, I found that DB2 does support

`--update-key id`

but does not yet have support for

`--update-mode allowinsert`

Meaning you cannot do upserts to DB2 using sqoop, but you can do updates and inserts separately. For updates, simply use `--update-key id` and for inserts, remove the argument altogether.

However, it should be noted that if your data set contains updates & inserts and you try to do an insert without the `--update-key`, the export will fail. You first need to separate your data into new records/updated records and then push each of them individually.

Lastly, doing an update where there are also new records will simply ignore the new records and will not fail. However, the new records will not be inserted even though the sqoop stdout tells you all records were exported.